# java comparable interface in sorting

Tags: java, collections, compareto

I came up with the problem in sets is to build my own default sorting order using comparable interface. I want to arrange `(int eid,String ename)` in descending order based on `eid` only. So this was the logic I couldnt understand in the `comapreTo` method.

```
public class First implements Comparable<First> {

private final int eId;
private final String eName;

public First(int eId, String  eName){
    this.eId = eId;
    this.eName = eName;
}

public int getEId() {
    return eId;
}

public String toString(){
    return eName + "------" + eId;
}

public int compareTo(First obj){
    int eId1 = this.eId;
    First f = (First) obj;
    int eId2 = f.eId;
    if (eId1 < eId2){ 
        return -1;
    } else if (eId1 > eId2){
        return +1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}}
```

please explain how this works and is there any other way of implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I haven't seen you express understanding to the part of your question which asks "how it works" I guess you still might not be clear on that end. I see you don't understand the "logic" behind some of the code based on your comments in some of the answers too.

We will take the example given by Mark Rotteveel to explain the logic as I believe that was a decent way to implement `compareTo`.

```
public int compareTo(First other){
if (eId < other.getEId()){ 
    return -1;
} else if (eId > other.getEId()){
    return +1;
} else {
    return 0;
}
}
```

We have the method `compareTo` take in a parameter which is an object of the type `First` - which is the class you created. This type includes all the properties that you have included in this class, for example having a `getEId` method that allows you return the private global variable `eId` that you find within your class `First`.

Now the thing is this `other` parameter in the `compareTo` is it's **own instance** of a `First` object, and not the same one you are comparing with inside the `compareTo` method (this part:  `if (eId < other.getEId())`).

Inside the `compareTo` method we use a if-else statement to check if `eId` (which refers to your current global variable `eId`) to the `eId` that was created for the `First` object that was passed as an argument to the `compareTo` method. So these two are **not the same value**.

As you said you are new to programming think of it this way, you made a class `First` that has a constructor:

```
public First(int eId, String  eName){
this.eId = eId;
this.eName = eName;
}
```

You can then make two *different* `First` objects as such:

```
First obj1 = new First(5, "Object 1");
First obj2 = new First(12, "Object 2");
```

In this example `obj1` and `obj2` are *not* the same object, and inherently have different `eId` values. The one you pass into the `compareTo`method might be `obj2` for example, which would be different from the eId that it's currently comparing to.

So when we pass `obj2` into the method like this `compareTo(obj2)`, this would mean that when it reaches the part of the code that reads `other.getEId` it would perform `obj2.getEId` which would obviously return a different `eId` than the `eId` inside the if statement. In this example '`obj2.getEId`' it would return the integer 12, because as you see I set `eId` as 12 for `obj2` earlier.

The rest of the code in the if-else statement is pretty straightforward, if the `eId` you are currently comparing with is of lesser value in terms of an integer, `return -1`, `else if` its greater `return +1` to move it up or down to sort them according to their `eId`. Return 0 in any other case because in that case they would be equal in terms of `eId`.

I hope that clarifies the code a bit in terms of the logic behind things and how the instances of `eId` compared within `compareTo` are different.

Answer (score 1):

The equals method and `==` and `!=` operators test for equality/inequality, but do not provide a way to test for relative values. Some classes (eg, String and other classes with a natural ordering) implement the Comparable interface, which defines a `compareTo` method. You will want to implement `Comparable<T>` in your class if you want to use it with `Collections.sort()` or `Arrays.sort()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison method is lacking, a proper example would be:

```
public int compareTo(First other){
    if (eId < other.getEId()){ 
        return -1;
    } else if (eId > other.getEId()){
        return +1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

By typing the Comparable interface, you can tell what kind of data gets compared. This ensures proper comparisons. Your example could run into a `NullPointerException` really quickly.

Comment: I have removed your flame of the op; it didn't answer the question and only serves to distract from your actual answer. In the future please use comments to point out deficiencies in a question, and remember to [be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: Thanks for the help I have edited the code next time will make sure it wont be repeated. Im a newbie to programming can you please explain how your logic works .

Answer (score 1):

> please explain how this works

I guess your question is basically,

> Why do I need to implement the comparable interface to sort a list?

To sort a list, you first need to tell Java how to compare two objects. This way, Java can figure out which object is "less" and which is "greater". Using this information, the list can then be sorted in an ascending order, or a descending order.

How do you tell Java which is greater and which is less?

If `this` is greater than the `other` argument, return 1. If `this` is less than the `other` argument, return -1. Otherwise, return 0.

> is there any other way of implementation?

Actually, your current `compareTo` method doesn't compile. A better implementation would be:

```
public int compareTo(First other){
    return Integer.compare(this.getEId(), other.getEId());
}
```

Comment: `this` and `other` both calls the same variable right?

Comment: Yeah. You call `getEId` on both `this` and `other`. Then use `Integer.compare` to compare the return values. @Digs

Comment: If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark. @Digs

Comment: I meant if both calling same variable value  then its comparing the same value instead of other.

Comment: @Digs Ah I see why you misunderstood now. You need to learn that `this` and `other` are _different_ instances of `First` when you sort the list by calling `Collections.sort`. `this` and `other` are completely independent of each other. In other words, the value of `this.getEId()` has nothing to do with the value of `other.getEId()`.

Comment: @Digs If you dig into the super complicated logic of `Arrays.sort`, you will find this `((Comparable) dest[j-1]).compareTo(dest[j])>0` at line 1349 of Arrays.java. As you can see, the sort method compares the object at index `j - 1` with the one at index `j`. So `this` and `other` are actually different objects.